# which is the dot net orm technology which works with salesforce and azure or any other environment

Tags: .net, azure, orm, salesforce

my requirement is to chose an ORM for .net which can deal with sales force and azure data or any other cloud based data base.
for example, if I search customer detail it should fetch from salesforce as well as azure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but tool/framework recommendation questions are off-topic. As far as  "cloud based" data goes: I don't understand that either - how do you categorize data as cloud-based, and how is that different from other data? I just don't see how there's any difference.

Answer (score -1):

> my requirement is to chose an ORM for .net which can deal with sales force and azure data or any other cloud based data base.

dotConnect for Salesforce offers an easy way to integrate Salesforce services into .NET applications and the highest performance. And dotConnect providers support such ORMs as Entity Framework, NHibernate, and LinqConnect, closely compatible to Microsoft LINQ to SQL, while extending its functionality with its own features. For more information, please refer to [this documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.dotConnectADONETDataProviderforSalesforce).